# CMake is not creating executables with access to my shared library

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake

I am working to switch an existing project from manual Makefiles to CMake (because the project is growing quite large), but there is an issue when I run an executable which is linked to a shared library which I create.

The my directory structure is as follows:

```
--CMakeLists.txt
--include
  |
  --include_files.h
--src
  |
  --src_files.cpp
--test
  |
  --CMakeLists.txt
  --test1.cpp
```

The CMakeLists.txt in the root directory is as follows:

```
project(Project)
include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/)
file(GLOB SOURCES "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.cpp")
add_library(Project SHARED ${SOURCES})
include_directories($ENV{EXTERN_INCLUDE}/lnInclude)
target_link_libraries(Project PRIVATE "$ENV{EXTERN_LIBBIN}/libextern.so")
add_subdirectory(test)
```

The CMakeLists.txt in the test directory is as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.9)
include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/)
add_executable(test1 test1.cpp)
include_directories($ENV{EXTERN_INCLUDE}/lnInclude)
target_link_libraries(test1 PRIVATE "$ENV{EXTERN_LIBBIN}/libextern.so")
add_dependencies(test1 Project)
target_link_libraries(test1 PUBLIC ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/libProject.so)
```

When I run cmake, then make, the shared library libProject.so is built (no errors), and the executable test1 is created, but when test1 is run, there are errors during runtime.

If I add these lines to the CMakeLists.txt in the test directory, the executable and shared library are built, and work perfectly:

```
file(GLOB SOURCES "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.cpp")
add_executable(test1 test1.cpp ${SOURCES})
```

This is not ideal though, because it means that I am compiling the src twice.

I have also tried to manually construct the Makefile for the test, but not the shared library, and this works fine without having to recompile the src. This makes me think that the issue is due to my use of cmake.

My question is: How do I correctly link the test executable with the shared library using CMake?

An example of the runtime error is as follows:

```
A was returned outside range, A=-nan
```

Inside the test function, I construct a class and pass it some info (node is defined in include and compiled into libProject.so):

```
Node& station1(*new Node(station1));
station1.X(X);
station1.Y(Y);
station1.Z(Z);
```

Then I call the functions of the class:

```
station1.A();
```

I expect this function to return a number in a predefined range, but it does not.

This is the output from gdb which makes me suspect that the shared library is not being loaded:

```
Function "Node::A()" not defined.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) y
Breakpoint 3 (Node::A()) pending.
(gdb) continue
Continuing.
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::range_error'
what():  Error: A lower than 0
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the runtime errors you get. Copy-paste eventual output as text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the `test1` target, don't manually add the dependency to `Project` or link with the `libProject.so` file.

Instead let CMake handle everything, simply by doing e.g.

```
include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/)
add_executable(test1 test1.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test1 Project)
```

Note that I also removed the `extern` dependency. If the test program doesn't actually use that library it's not needed..